# Modified energy method for transformed Fokker-Planck equation (tricky integration by parts…)

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, differential-inequalities

I came across Villani's paper titled *"Hypocoercive diffusion operators"* and couldn't figure out a computation that is skipped in that paper. Specifically, consider the following transformed Fokker-Planck equation, where $h(t,x,v)$ is the unknown, $(x,v) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$, $V(x)$ is some potential force: $$\partial_t h + v\cdot \nabla_x h - \nabla V(x)\cdot \nabla_v h = \Delta_v h - v\cdot \nabla_v h.$$ Notice that the Laplacian $\Delta_v$ is only a partial Laplacian in the sense that it only acts on the velocity variables $v$, and for the usual $L^2$ energy $\int h^2 d\mu$, where $d\mu = f_\infty(x,v) dxdv$ and $f_\infty(x,v) = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\left(V(x)+\frac{|v|^2}{2}\right)}}{Z}$ with $Z$ a normalization constant making $f_\infty$ a probability density in $(x,v) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$, and we easily have $\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} \int h^2 d\mu = -\int |\nabla_v h|^2 d\mu$. Then the author says under suitable assumptions on $V$, we can find suitable constants $a,c, K>0$ so that $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int h^2 d\mu + a\int |\nabla_x h|^2 d\mu + c\int |\nabla_v h|^2 d\mu \right) \leq -K\left(\int |\nabla_v h|^2 d\mu + \int |\nabla_v\nabla_x h|^2 d\mu + \int |\nabla_v\nabla_v h|^2 d\mu\right). $$ However, I have no clue why the above inequality holds (and justifying it in 1D should be enough for me, i.e., in the case $(x,v) \in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$). What I did is the following (in 1D setting). Set
$$I(t):=\left(a\int |\nabla_x h|^2 d\mu + c\int |\nabla_v h|^2 d\mu \right).$$
Then
\begin{align*}
\frac 12\frac{dI}{dt} &= -a\int |\partial_v\partial_x h|^2 d\mu - c\int |\partial_v\partial_v h|^2 d\mu - c\int |\partial_v h|^2 d\mu\\
&\quad \color{red}{+ a\int \partial_x h \partial_x\left(V'(x)\partial_v h\right) - v\partial_xh\partial_{xx}h~d\mu} \\
&\quad \color{red}{+c\int V'(x)\partial_vh\partial_{vv}h - \partial_vh\left(\partial_x h+v\partial_v\partial_xh\right)~d\mu}
\end{align*}
But I have no clue as to the treatment of the terms in red. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I have also asked this question on Math Stack Exchange (the link is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782421/modified-energy-method-for-transformed-fokker-planck-equation-tricky-integratio) and no satisfying answer is given as well.

Comment: Multiply through by $h$, integrate, and use integration by parts.

Comment: @Aruralreader Can you elaborate more? For instance, multiply "who" through $h$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a worked-out proof in page 10 and following of [Hérau's lecture notes.](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01616979/document) The detailed steps are for $n=1$, $V=0$, but I assume once that is understood, the more general case would follow smoothly.

As a short-hand notation we write $ \|\partial_x h \|^2=\int (\partial h/\partial x)^2\,d\mu$ and $\langle\partial_x h,\partial_v h\rangle=\int (\partial h/\partial x)(\partial h/\partial v)\,d\mu$. We will make use of the identities
$$\langle f,\partial_v g\rangle=\langle(-\partial_v+v)f,g\rangle,$$
$$\langle v\partial_x f,f\rangle=0$$
$$[\partial_v ,v\partial_x]=\partial_x,$$
and the [Cauchy-Schwartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) + [Young inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products#Elementary_case)
$$2|c\langle\partial_v f,\partial_x f\rangle|\leq 2c \|\partial_v f \|\, \|\partial_x f \|\leq c^2 \|\partial_v f \|^2+ \|\partial_x f \|^2.$$
The Fokker-Planck equation for $n=1$, $V=0$ reads
$$\partial_t h+Lh=0,\;\;L=v\partial_x + (-\partial_v+v)\partial_v .$$
The adjoint of $L$ is
$$L^\ast=-v\partial_x + (-\partial_v+v)\partial_v.$$

The resulting derivatives are
$$-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt} \|h \|^2= \|\partial_v h \|^2,$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt} \|\partial_x h \|^2= \|\partial_v\partial_x h \|^2,$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt} \|\partial_v h \|^2=\langle\partial_x h,\partial_v h\rangle+ \|(-\partial_v +v)\partial_v h \|^2=\langle\partial_x h,\partial_v h\rangle+ \|\partial_v^2 h \|^2+ \|\partial_v h \|^2.$$

So the derivative $dI/dt$ in the OP reduces to
$$\frac{dI}{dt}=-2a \|\partial_v\partial_x h \|^2-2c\biggl(\langle\partial_x h,\partial_v h\rangle+ \|\partial_v^2 h \|^2+ \|\partial_v h \|^2\biggr)$$
$$\qquad\leq -2a \|\partial_v\partial_x h \|^2-2c \|\partial_v^2 h \|^2-(2c-c^2) \|\partial_v h \|^2+ \|\partial_x h \|^2.$$
It remains to bound $ \|\partial_x h \|^2$.

In the lecture notes they do this by adding the mixed term $b\langle\partial_x h,\partial_v h\rangle$ to the left-hand-side of the inequality, which then gives a term $-b \|\partial_x h \|^2$ on the right-hand-side to dominate. Let me work that out, using the derivative$^{\ast}$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\langle\partial_x h,\partial_v h\rangle=- \|\partial_x h \|^2-2\langle\partial_v\partial_x h,\partial_v\partial_v h\rangle-\langle\partial_x h,\partial_v h\rangle,$$
hence
$$\frac{d}{dt}J\equiv\frac{d}{dt}\biggl( \|h \|^2+a \|\partial_x h \|^2+b\langle\partial_x h,\partial_v h\rangle+c \|\partial_v h \|^2\biggr)=$$
$$\qquad=-2(c+1) \|\partial_v h \|^2-2a \|\partial_v\partial_x h \|^2-b \|\partial_x h \|^2-2c\|\partial_v\partial_v h\|^2-2b\langle\partial_v\partial_x h,\partial_v\partial_v h\rangle-(b+2c)\langle\partial_x h,\partial_v h\rangle.$$
The first four terms on the right-hand-side have a fixed sign, the last two terms can be bounded by the Cauchy-Schwartz + Young inequality.

---

<sub>$^\ast$ The result for $(d/dt)\langle\partial_x h,\partial_v h\rangle$ given on page 10 of the cited lecture notes is mistaken. Here is a derivation:</sub>

<sub>\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\langle\partial_x h,\partial_v h\rangle&=-\langle\partial_x Lh,\partial_v h\rangle-\langle\partial_x h,\partial_v Lh\rangle\\
&=-\langle\partial_x h,(L^\ast\partial_v +\partial_v L)h\rangle,\\
L^\ast\partial_v +\partial_v L&=\bigl(-v\partial_x+(-\partial_v+v)\partial_v\bigr)\partial_v+\partial_v\bigl(v\partial_x+(-\partial_v+v)\partial_v\bigr)\\
&=\partial_x+\partial_v+2(-\partial_v+v)\partial_v\partial_v,\\
\Rightarrow\frac{d}{dt}\langle\partial_x h,\partial_v h\rangle&=-\|\partial_x h\|^2-\langle\partial_x h,\partial_v h\rangle-2\langle\partial_x h,(-\partial_v+v)\partial_v\partial_v h\rangle\\
&=-\|\partial_x h\|^2-\langle\partial_x h,\partial_v h\rangle-2\langle\partial_v\partial_x h,\partial_v\partial_v h\rangle.
\end{align}</sub>

Comment: Thanks! But my problem is to derive inequality (11) in details. (If you read my problem statement carefully...)

Comment: Thanks! I will digest them and examine in details of your calculation, I will finish this within today

Comment: The only difference introducing the $V$ term is that $dI / dt$ includes additionally the term $+2a \int \partial_x h \partial_v h V'' ~d\mu$; if you have good control on the Hessian of $V$ then this term can be treated in the same way as the $-2c \langle \partial_x h, \partial_v h\rangle$ term.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Actually I have several questions. (1) I do not see why $\langle v\partial_x f,f\rangle=0$ (2) the meaning of $[\partial_v v,\partial_x]=1$ is not clear (3) for $ n = 1$ and $V = 0$ the PDE reads as $\partial_t h+v\partial_x h + v\partial_v h - \Delta_v h=0$, not $\partial_t h+v\partial_x h+(-\partial_v+v)h=0.$

Comment: (1) $\langle v\partial_xf,f\rangle=-\langle f,v\partial_x f\rangle=\langle f,v\partial_x f\rangle\Rightarrow \langle v\partial_x f,f\rangle=0$; (2) $[\partial_v v,\partial_x]\equiv \partial_v v\partial_x-\partial_x\partial_v v =\partial_x$; (the "1" was a typo); (3) that was also a typo; there may be more typo's, it's quite a lengthy calculation.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker sorry I know think your answer to (1) is correct, it is not well-explained somehow

Comment: sorry, I don't understand the calculations $[\partial_v v,\partial_x]\equiv \partial_v v\partial_x-\partial_x\partial_v v =\partial_x$, $\partial_v v = 1$ right?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker can you add more details about the computation behind $\frac{d}{dt}\langle\partial_x h,\partial_v h\rangle=-||\partial_x h||^2+2\langle(-\partial_v+v)\partial_v h,\partial_v\partial_x h\rangle-\langle\partial_x h,\partial_v h\rangle$?

Comment: @FeiCao: I don't know why you have performed that edit, because there was no typo there: the two formulas (before and after the edit) are equal.

Comment: @AlexM. Originally CarloBeenakker wrote the wrong PDE

Comment: @FeiCao: Carlo Beenakker had written $(-\partial_v+v)\partial_v h$ and you have changed that into $v\partial_v h - \partial_v\partial_v h$, which is a bit useless given that the two are equal. This has nothing to with the PDE being right or wrong.

Comment: @AlexM. Ok now I see your points...

Comment: @CarloBeenakker If you don't mind, I really want to ask your the question on the computation of $\frac{d}{dt}\langle\partial_x h,\partial_v h\rangle$, in page 10 of the reference notes, after the sentence "The time derivative of the third term can be computed as follows", I cannot get the same expression as the author, my last term is $\langle -\partial_v\partial_v h,~\partial_x\partial_v h\rangle$ and not $\langle (-\partial_v + v)\partial_v h,~\partial_x\partial_v h\rangle$ and I cannot correct this part...

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thanks! A small request as well: please be careful about the computations and type-ohs, your single type-oh may waste more than an hour of your reader, that's why I always triple triple triple check the stuff I wrote, I personally never want my reader to find a mistake or type-oh that will waste their time. Best.

Comment: you are right, that is an error in Hérau's lecture notes; I presume it does not break the inequality, but you'll want to check that.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker thanks! i checked the computations and now it is correct. A final question, the author of the notes mentioned a use of the Poincare inequality in space and velocity, how does that inequality work (it's my first time encountering Poincare inequality in multiple-variables...)?

Comment: Poincaré inequality: the analysis in the lecture notes applies to functions of zero mean in both $x$ and $v$, then the left-hand-side of the Poincaré inequality, the variance with respect to $x$ or $v$, is just the $L_2$ norm; the right-hand-side then bounds that by $\|h\|^2\leq c_x \|\partial_x \|^2$ and $\| h\|^2\leq c_v\|\partial_v\|^2$; Hérau sets $c_v=1$ (unit spectral gap) and denotes $c_x\equiv c_p$; on page 11 these two inequalities are applied, I would think $c_p$ should be $c_p+1$, but that only makes the inequality stronger.